# AWS CLI - Get all CloudFormation stacks that have a name that starts with string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, jmespath

What query should I use to get all CloudFormation stacks that start with a specific string?

I have tried the following query, but it always returns an empty array:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --no-paginate --query "Stacks[?StackName!='null']|[?starts_with(StackName,'HD-') == 'true']"
```

All the stacks in our account start with "HD-", so this should return the same as

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --no-paginate
```

But it returns

```
[]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command works fine:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --no-paginate --query \
  'Stacks[?StackName!=`null`]|[?contains(StackName, `Release`) == `true`].StackName'
```

It looks like you need to use ` rather than ' inside the query..